# How to draw a rectangle around an <Array>Rectangle

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Trying the Shape renderer but it just aint workin =P Trying to debug some hitboxes that aren't acting correctly.

```
    carb = new Array<Rectangle>();
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = carb.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle car2 = iter.next();


    batch.end();

    sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    sr.setColor(new Color(0,0,1,0));
    sr.rect(carb.getPosition(position).x, carb.getPosition(position).y, carb.getSize(position).x, carb.getSize(position).y);
    sr.end();
```

^ Getting the error "The method getPosition/getSize is undefined for the type rectangle"

Comment: How many rectangles do you want to draw? Only one or one for every single `Rectangle` object?

Comment: Just the Car2's at first, but if they look fine then i'll pull up the others

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating `carb` via `iter`, then accessing element called `car2` (this holds current object, the one you want to draw a rectangle around). After that you're calling `sr.rect()` with `carb.getPosition()`. `carb` is still an array and you should call `car2.getPosition()/Size()` instead. Array doesn't have `getPosition()` method, but `Rectangle` does.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, but now it's asking me to initialise Car2 o.o

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand your code.
carb is ArrayList, why you call carb.getPosition(position).x
I think it should be carb.get(position).getPosition().x